# DataGridView's 'RowValidating' event fires differently when closing a MODAL v. NON-MODAL form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Based on our tests primarily done in VB.NET in VS2010 it seems that when you close a WinForm the "RowValidating" event of the DataGridView on that form behaves differently depending on whether the form is MODAL or NON-MODAL. What we did was open the form (MODAL and NONMODAL) and changed a value of a cell and then immediately clicked the "X" to close the form. It looks like the "RowValidating" event DOESN'T fire if the grid is on a MODAL form but it DOES fire when the grid is on a NON-MODAL form. We can't figure out why that is... Is this a known bug in .NET?

Here's our test. You can run in the immediate window by typing and seeing if you get the RowValidating popup from the handler:

```
_SandboxTest.DataGridViewTestModal
or
_SandboxTest.DataGridViewTestNonModal
```

here's the code:

```
Module _SandboxTest
     Sub DataGridViewTestNonModal()
        Dim frm As New Form

        Dim dtable As New DataTable()
        dtable.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Column1"), New DataColumn("Column2"), New DataColumn("Column3")})
        dtable.Rows.Add({"test", "abc", "def"})
        dtable.Rows.Add({"test2", "abc2", "def2"})
        Dim dg As New DataGridView
        dg.DataSource = dtable
        dg.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        Try
            AddHandler dg.RowValidating, AddressOf RowValidatingHandler
            frm.Controls.Add(dg)

            frm.Show()
            Do
                Application.DoEvents()
            Loop While frm.Visible
        Finally
            RemoveHandler dg.RowValidating, AddressOf RowValidatingHandler
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub DataGridViewTestModal()
        Dim frm As New Form

        Dim dtable As New DataTable()
        dtable.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Column1"), New DataColumn("Column2"), New DataColumn("Column3")})
        dtable.Rows.Add({"test", "abc", "def"})
        dtable.Rows.Add({"test2", "abc2", "def2"})
        Dim dg As New DataGridView
        dg.DataSource = dtable
        dg.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        Try
            AddHandler dg.RowValidating, AddressOf RowValidatingHandler
            frm.Controls.Add(dg)

            frm.ShowDialog()
        Finally
            RemoveHandler dg.RowValidating, AddressOf RowValidatingHandler
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub RowValidatingHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs)
        MsgBox("RowValidating was fired!")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx

Have posted this question on a few sites so any change can be seen here or there. The jist of the matter is that it seems that it is a BUG with Microsoft's implements of DataGridView although they are refusing to fix it.

One way to get around this is to trigger the Validating yourself onFormClose/OnFormClosing:

```
 Private Sub MyFormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        Dim f = DirectCast(sender, Form)
        If f.Modal AndAlso Not f.ValidateChildren Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here are the links where I posted this question also (to monitor changes):

```
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/cd0b6e1a-9453-4092-b764-b93e612dda51
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653413/datagridviews-rowvalidating-event-fires-differently-when-closing-a-modal-v-nonmodal-form#details
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why this happens for you but I just did a test on one of our non-modal forms and the RowValidating event does fire when we close it.

**Edit:**

I could now reproduce the issue. With a non-modal form the RowValidating does fire, but with a modal form it doesn't. That's strange, I'm pretty sure it's a bug. You can always call Me.ValidateChildren before the form is closed to force controls in the form to validate.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it will help if I can convert our tests to something that I can post...

Comment: I posted our tests above. I think I originally had the Modal/Non-Modal behavior flipped. Non-Modal fires and Modal doesn't.